# Makefile not creating executable. Is including a .txt file causing the error?

Tags: c++, makefile

For a class I am taking we are learning to use Makefiles. My issue is when I run my files altogether I get an error in the compiler letting me know that my file could not be cleaned and that there is no directory for it.
I've ran this many times without the .txt file and still there is no directory found for the file in question. I've looked at the GNU guidelines but do not see an example with .txt files so I'm wondering if that could be the issue. My makefile code is below

```
CXX = g++  # the compiler
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++17 -Wall  # flags for the compiler (use c++17 standards, turn on all optional warnings);

all: main
    
main: pe3_references.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) pe3_bash.txt pe3_references.cpp main
    
clean: 
    rm main
```

This is the pe3_bash.txt file. Just Answers.

```
1. pwd
2. vim empty.txt
3. ls empty*
4. ls *.txt | wc -l
5. echo "Tj Mmorosa" > empty.txt
6. mv empty.txt notempty.txt
7. mkdir pe3_bash
8. cd pe3_bash
9. mkdir pe3_bash_number2
10. cd pe3_bash_number2
11. Up key shows previous inputs to terminal
12. Down key moves in reverse direction of inputs to terminal
13. ctrl+r is used to search previous commands
14. 1)vim empty.txt
      nano empty.txt
    2) :wq (for vim)
      ctrl+x (for nano)
    3) :q (vim)
        ctrl+x (nano)
15. Command line text editors are quicker and easily accessible.
*/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl0wf.png)
I would greatly appreciate some insight. (Btw only files I have are a pe3_references.cpp, pe3_bash.txt, and the Makefile if that helps)

Comment: Which directory are you talking about? And what does the text file do? Why do you pass it to the compiler?

Comment: Its just a directory on my machine. The textfile is a part of the homework assignment with answers. We have to pass it to the compiler because there is an autograder that will accept the makefile and run the pe3_references.cpp file.

Comment: Could you show the full output of running this makefile?

Comment: I think you probably need to pass the text file when you execute the code, not when you compile it

Comment: @tkausl I have added the screenshot to the post.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't think I follow would I just add another target? If so what would the body of that target contain? I'm still very new to Makefiles.

Comment: The clean isn't the problem, your compile command is. Remove the text file and change `main` to `-o main`.

Comment: Each line in a Makefile rule is executed by the shell. Unless `pe3_bash.txt` is executable and contains a correct interpreter selection (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env XXX`), then it should not be in the line `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) pe3_bash.txt pe3_references.cpp main` Rather than making everyone guess, please shown the contents of `pe3_bash.txt`

Comment: @tkausl I tried it but it did not work. Still it says no such file or directory.

Comment: Again, _this error is not your problem_, just ignore it. Look at the compiler error.

Comment: @tkausl sorry but I don't think I understand the compiler is telling me it couldn't clean that's why it gave out errors. Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: Your text file doesn't need to be in the make file at all, just pass it as an argument when you run your program

Comment: If you want to compile `pe3_references.cpp` to an executable named `main`, your command should be `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) pe3_references.cpp -o main`. Please change the command, and if you are still getting errors, please *ask a different question about these errors*. **Do not post screenshots of errors**, use text.

Comment: It Worked finally. @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You are correct I believe there was an error within my code.